# Unable to compile YamlDotNet csproj

Tags: yamldotnet

I've cloned the official YamlDotNet git repository.
https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet

However I'm unable to compile the solution

- Failed in Visual Studio 2017
- Failed using the build.ps1 script in the repo

I get the same error.

- Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
- Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported

I've already tried...

- doing a git clean -xfd, and recompiling to no avail
- I've also tried only deleting the bin/ obj/ folders and attempt recompiling to no avail

Additional Details

- I have a bunch of different .net framework's installed, including 4.5
- I also have installed .net core SDK 2.2

Is anyone else getting this issue?